# Check 3gp file is audio/video in Android?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, video, mime-types

Im trying to get mimetype of video files using below code.

**Porblem: I have a file saved as audio but its mimetype is video/3gpp and it is also playing
as Audio.** . How to detect this kind of file which is audio but mimetype is video/3gpp in its
details so i can exclude it from list.

```
fun getFileMimeType(url: String): String {

        var type: String = ""

        try {
            if (url.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
                val ext: String = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)
                val mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext)!!
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }

        return type

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a local file, you can use MediaMetadataRetriever to get Metadata information about the media file.

Specifically, you can check if the METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO is set to true.

An example in Kotlin:

```js
        val metadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        metadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(your3GPPFile))

        val hasVideoKey = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO)
        if (hasVideoKey == "yes") {
          //Include in your list or do whatever work 
          //you need here
        }
```

You can also use ExoPlayer and load the file, and then get a list of the tracks using

> player.getCurrentTrackGroups()

This will return an array of tracks which you can loop through and parse the format to check if they include a video track.

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved the issue using MediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: This is perfect. I needed it as a fallback for container formats such as 3gpp which always return video/3gpp even if the file only contains an audio track only.